# Getting wrong hash in location header on Http request

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpurlconnection, request-headers

I am trying to make a Bookstore application. To download any book there is a redirect link that contains the actual link with the filename to download the epub file. But when I load the first link and try to get the redirect link from the location header I get the wrong link.

Code:

```
String url = "https://1lib.in/dl/4649171/4e15a5";
URL url2 = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
            httpConn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            httpConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36");
            httpConn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.google.com");
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("LocationHeader",responseCode+" <-code");
            String locate = httpConn.getHeaderField("Location");
            Log.d("LocationHeader",locate+" <-location");
```

This is the response that I get.

```
LocationHeader: 302 <-code
LocationHeader: https://1lib.in/book/4649171/371aea/?wrongHash <-location
```

Expected Result:

```
LocationHeader: https://p302.zlibcdn.com/dtoken/aaa62058cd53e7318e2f511f4d1fbd3f <-location
```

Also tried the request in Postman but got the same results there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that is not a Java issue. Have you tried the same request with `curl`or `postman`? It seems that the problem is the request itself, or the in the server, it if is not returning what it is expected.

Comment: Please do not post external links or images, add the additional information to your original question. If the request it is failing also with Postman/curl, then the problem is not your java code, but the problem is on the side of the server.

Comment: Try `https://1lib.in/dl/4649171/57a87a` this URL with your same code. I believe it should download something. (Not sure if it is really the same epub file you want). But ff it works it means, you have used the wrong URL `https://1lib.in/book/4649171/371aea` or the URL is changed on the server/db/backend.

Comment: Please do not post external links or images.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero Sorry I added additional links in the comment section. I am new to writing questions in StackOverflow. I added them to the original question.

Comment: @miiiii I tried the link that you gave me but I still got the same results.

Comment: You are adding external links, you must avoid doing that, please include any additional information directly into the question

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero The links are of the same domain as mentioned in the OP's question and is posted in form of a code sample( for `HttpURLConnection`)

Comment: @miiiii, you are talking about other links (the links of the HTTP request), but the OP has already fixed the links we are talking about (links to external images to explain the question).

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero Cool.

Comment: What could be the issue with the request for not giving the expected location header string? I even tried with OkHttp but still no luck

Comment: @PranjalChaudhari Do you own/work with `1lib`? If yes, you must talk to the internal team about the server's behavior as it is not programming problem. 

The site I observed is providing hash based on the user's IP (maybe to track or Limit some feature). I tried from Indian IP (for `.in`) the URL was different & when tried from Poland the URL for the same epub was different. I also get the error "You have used all 5 free downloads for guest User on your IP". 

It doesn't look like truly a programming issue but understanding of a particular application & it's internal behavior is required.

Comment: @miiiii Thank you for looking into the matter. I also believe that the server is generating a hash token based on IP and hence I am getting the wrong hash each time a send a request. I don't work/own the `1Lib`. If that's the case, will I not be able to fetch the header correctly if I do not know the server's behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It looks like the owner/development team has done it in order to restrict such downloads and hence it's part of their system design. Even if any workaround/loophole is possible, I cannot talk about it and you should also not try downloading their content without their consent (if any). 

Whenever you think this question is not solvable/relevant, please delete your post so that others can avoid getting caught here. However, it is not mandatory. :)